# auto slide out with checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, slide

I'm a rookie in jquery and want to learn for myself. I have red box using  with checkbox inside of the red box.

what I like to have is that when load the page while uncheck, is automatic red box slide out if the user wants to slide in all have to do is mouse over on red box slide in.

I also have a checkbox for turn off automatic slide out, another word means stay view with out slide out.

I have written code but is not working, I guess it must merge two jquerys for ( slideout and checkbox)... I need help to have both auto slideout or slide in with checkbox that if checkbox checked then turn off auto slideout or slide in.

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alidad3250/yp43vnxz/13/)

see the code ...

```
<!--auto hide and show right sidebar-->   

$(window).on("load", function() {
   $(".sidebar-nav-right").animate({ "right": "-=150px" }, "slow" );
});

$(window).on("load", function() {
   $(".sidebar-nav-right").animate({ "right": "-=150px" }, "fast" );
});


$(".sidebar-nav-right").hover(function () {
    $(".sidebar-nav-right").animate({ "right": "0px" }, "fast" );
}, function(){
     $(".sidebar-nav-right").animate({ "right": "-=150px" }, "fast" );
});


<!--checkbox -->

$('#mycheckbox').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $(".sidebar-nav-right").addClass("sidebar-nav-rightb");
    $(".ui-sortable").css("width", "1320px");
  } else {
    $(".sidebar-nav-right").removeClass("sidebar-nav-rightb");
     $(".ui-sortable").css("width", "100%");
  }
});

<div class="sidebar-nav-right">

<div><input type="checkbox" id"mycheckbox">checkbox</div>

right sidebar

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you'll need to address for this. First of all, you'll want to wrap your jQuery in a

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code goes here
})
```

Second, you are missing an `=` on the id for `mycheckbox`

Third, in order to set the `right` property of css, you first need to set the `position`

here is your updated code that seems to be working in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yp43vnxz/16/, it will at least give you a start in the right direction

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sidebar-nav-right").animate({ "right": "-50" }, "slow" );

$('#mycheckbox').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $(".sidebar-nav-right").addClass("sidebar-nav-rightb");
        $(".ui-sortable").css("width", "1320px");
  } else {
    $(".sidebar-nav-right").removeClass("sidebar-nav-rightb");
      $(".ui-sortable").css("width", "100%");
  }
});

$(".sidebar-nav-right").hover(function () {
        if(!$('#mycheckbox').prop("checked")) {
      $(".sidebar-nav-right").animate({ "right": "10px" }, "fast" );
     } 

}, function(){
        if(!$('#mycheckbox').prop("checked")) {
     $(".sidebar-nav-right").animate({ "right": "-=115px" }, "fast" );
    }
});

})
```

Comment: Thank you so much you were right about the id. thanks for your help.